# Opencv no rule to make target

Tags: opencv, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying out the example to convert ros image to opencv image from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages). I am creating a new package `roscv_conv` and using a zed camera with ros indigo, on a `Jetson tx1`, to get this done (I will probably have to edit the topic being subscribed to , given in the example). I have installed OpenCV4Tegra (version 2.4.12.2). But my current issue is that I am receiving the following error during `catkin_make` :

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.8', needed by `/home/ubuntu/tst_ws/devel/lib/roscv_conv/roscv_conv_node'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [roscv_conv/CMakeFiles/roscv_conv_node.dir/all] Error 2
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(roscv_conv)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  
)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge image_transport roscpp sensor_msgs std_msg
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(roscv_conv_node src/roscv_conv_node.cpp)

target_link_libraries(roscv_conv_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
)
add_dependencies(roscv_conv_node sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp)
```

Also, I have the following lines in my `package.xml` :

```
<build_depend>OpenCV</build_depend>
<run_depend>OpenCV</run_depend>
```

How do I fix this issue? I believe it has nothing to do with the actual code inside the src folder.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241027/opencv-no-rule-to-make-target/) by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2016-08-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

same problem here. In my case I'm using rpi3 with jessie. Our CMakeList.txt and package.xml are completely the same.

Did you find any solution?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I figured out how to solve this problem. Probably it is a shoddy job, but the case is that it worked for me.

My case is RPI3 + Jessie + ROS Indigo (base)

I installed opencv (sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev) which comes with the 2.4.9 version.

So far everything is running right.

After that I installed image_transport and cv_bridge and the problem started to appear when a node included cv_bridge:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.8', needed by `/home/ubuntu/tst_ws/devel/lib/my_package/my_node'.  Stop.
```

I moved to where the opencv.so files are and created a symbolic link named "libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.8" and pointing to "libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.9". Catkin_make asked me to do the same with every "libopencv_something.so.2.4.8" I had.

Everything is running correctly now. I'm sure it is not a brilliant solution but, if a stupid idea works, probably is not that stupid!

---

Originally posted by [Nxt](https://answers.ros.org/users/27879/nxt/) with karma: 36 on 2016-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-09-01**:
I installed a normal OpenCV (not OpenCV4Tegra), version 2.4.13. In my case I found out that it is an issue with the platform.

**Comment by [Nxt](https://answers.ros.org/users/27879/nxt/) on 2016-09-02**:
Thank you! I finally found a solution that works for me, I edited my post with it.

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-09-14**:
I think the solution is similar for Jetson as well. Anyway, thank you for the info.